# C++ get random number in several ranges

Tags: c++

How I can get random number in several ranges? For example, I ask numbers in range 5-10 and 18-53.

My main goal is generate random password by using ASCII table (https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:ASCII-Table.svg). So I generate a random number 33-126. But before generating password I should ask about what password user wants (numbers, lowercase letters,  uppercase letters, symbols). When user ask me generate password for him with numbers and lowercase letters, I need get number 48-57 and 97-122.

I guess I can use smth like `do while` to generate number in loop till that moment when it is correct.

But mb there is a better option?

Comment: May be of interest: [std::piecewise_constant_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution).

Answer (score 2):

You can generate numbers in a contiguous range, and map those to the desired values.

```
template <std::uniform_random_bit_generator URBG>
char uniform_lower_alphanumeric(URBG&& gen) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution dist(0, 35);
    auto value = dist(gen);
    if (value < 10) return static_cast<char>('0' + value);
    return static_cast<char>('a' + value - 10);
}
```

Or more simply

```
template <std::uniform_random_bit_generator URBG>
char uniform_lower_alphanumeric(URBG&& gen) {
    auto lower_alphanumerics = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::uniform_int_distribution dist(0, std::size(lower_alphanumerics) - 1);
    return lower_alphanumerics[dist(gen)];
}
```

Comment: looks like you forgot to type `template<typename URBG>` or `auto` (c++20). Without this `&&` looks suspicious.

Comment: also difficult to understand by the op - and by me.

Comment: i agree about providing the set of characters you can pick from is a good idea. and if the set is mutable you can use fisher-yates shuffle to get unique values

Comment: `'a'-'z'` is not guaranteed to be contiguous (as EBCDIC). so prefer second approach.

Comment: I also prefer the second approach. Compact and understandable solution.
To make it adaptable I would propose to use distinct sets for lowercase letters, numbers, etc. and then compose the target set by just concatenating the strings.